# PSQL code missing

Tags: psql

My problem on getting one row shown with two null values.

```
FROM tuotemerkki;
         tmtunnus |  tmnimi  |     maa
        ----------+----------+-------------
                1 | McCee    | Yhdysvallat
                2 | KooTek   | Italia
                3 | Giardino | Italia
        (3 rows)

FROM tuote;
 ttunnus |         tnimi         |       kuvaus       | suositushinta | tmtunnus
---------+-----------------------+--------------------+---------------+----------
     111 | Trimmeri TRCee        | tehokas 4-tahtinen |        179.00 |        1
     112 | Trimmerisiima Cee     | laadukas siima     |          6.99 |        1
     113 | Moottorisaha MSCee RR | robusti ja raskas  |        559.00 |        1
     114 | Trimmerisiima Y       | yleissiima         |          3.99 |        2
     115 | Lapio L               | kevyt yleislapio   |         23.95 |        2
(5 rows)
```

I need to get this selected with the NULL VALUE on giardino from tmnimi.

```
  tmnimi  |         tnimi         |       kuvaus
----------+-----------------------+--------------------
 McCee    | Trimmeri TRCee        | tehokas 4-tahtinen
 McCee    | Trimmerisiima Cee     | laadukas siima
 McCee    | Moottorisaha MSCee RR | robusti ja raskas
 KooTek   | Trimmerisiima Y       | yleissiima
 KooTek   | Lapio L               | kevyt yleislapio
 Giardino |                       |
```

(6 rows)

I get only this selected

```
SELECT tmnimi, tnimi, kuvaus
    FROM tuote
    CROSS JOIN tuotemerkki
    WHERE tuote.tmtunnus = tuotemerkki.tmtunnus;

 tmnimi |         tnimi         |       kuvaus
--------+-----------------------+--------------------
 McCee  | Trimmeri TRCee        | tehokas 4-tahtinen
 McCee  | Trimmerisiima Cee     | laadukas siima
 McCee  | Moottorisaha MSCee RR | robusti ja raskas
 KooTek | Trimmerisiima Y       | yleissiima
 KooTek | Lapio L               | kevyt yleislapio
(5 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join between the two tables:

```
SELECT
    t1.tmnimi,
    t2.tnimi,
    t2.kuvaus
FROM tuotemerkki t1
LEFT JOIN tuote t2
    ON t1.tmtunnus = t2.tmtunnus
```

When you left join from `tuotemerkki` to `tuote`, then every record in the former table is guaranteed to appear in the result set.  Since the Giardino record does not match to anything in the `tuote` table, all the columns from that table would have a `NULL` value for the Giardino record.